# Not able to host Xero oAuth20 dll in Azure Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services, xero-api

I have implemented Xero oAuth20 in Asp.Net Web forms using Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2 -Version 0.4.0 version from Nuget package manager.
This is working fine in my local, how ever if I try to deploy solution in Azure server, the publish is getting failed.
Please help to fix this issue.
This is the error
"Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation."

Comment: Is there any particular error you get when publishing to Azure? 

Have you given these steps a try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926402/azure-web-deploy-publish-failed

Comment: @StevenMcD I have tried the above mentioned steps. This is the error I found in logs. "Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation."